# Show that $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n \rightarrow e^x$ uniformly on any bounded interval of the real line.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Show that $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n \rightarrow e^x$ uniformly on any bounded interval of the real line.

I am trying to argue from the definition of uniform convergence for a sequence of real-valued functions, but am struggling quite a lot. My efforts so far have concentrated on trying to find a sequences,
${a_n}$ which tends to zero, such that

$$|(1+\frac{x}{n})^n -e^x |\leq a_n$$ for all $n$. But I have been unsuccessful thus far. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The sequence is question is increasing and its limit is continuous.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your comment? I'm probably missing something simple.

Comment: There is a theorem that under the conditions in my comment the convergence is uniform on compact sets.

Comment: ...and said theorem goes by the name of Dini's theorem.

Comment: @Glitch Yeah thats it.

Comment: What a nice theorem. Thanks much!

Comment: But what about showing that the sequence of functions increases specificially to $e^x$?

Comment: The sequence is not increasing on all of $\mathbb R$ so let's be careful.

Comment: Note that $(\ln g(x))'= \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$. With $P_n(x) = (1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ you have $\frac{P_n'(x)}{P_n(x)}= \frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{n}} \to 1$ uniformly on any bounded interval, therefore $\ln P_n(x) = \int_0^x \frac{P'_n(y)}{P_n(y)}dy\to x$ uniformly on any bounded interval and $P_n(x )  \to e^x$ uniformly  on any bounded interval.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Herein, we present an approach that for any given $\epsilon>0$, produces a number $N$, which depends on $\epsilon$ and not $x$, such that $\displaystyle \left|e^x-\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\right|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$.

> To do this we will use the inequalities, which I established in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality.  The inequalities used in the ensuing analysis are

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{e^x\le 1+x} \tag 1$$

> for $x<-1$ and

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\log(x)\ge \frac{x-1}{x}} \tag 2$$

> for $x>0$.

> To this end, we proceed.

---

We assume that $x\in [a,b]$ and that $\epsilon>0$ is given. Furthermore, we will choose $n$ such that $n>-x$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Using $(1)$ and $(2)$ we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left|e^x-\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\right|&=\left|e^x-e^{n\log\left(1+\frac xn\right)}\right|\\\\
&\le \left|e^x-e^{\frac{x}{1+x/n}}\right|\\\\
&=e^x\,\left|1-e^{-x^2/(x+n)}\right|\\\\
&\le e^x\,\left|\frac{x^2}{x+n}\right|\\\\
&\le e^{b}\frac{|\max^2(a,b)|}{n+a}\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $ \displaystyle n>\frac{e^b\,\max^2(a,b)}{\epsilon}-a$.  We take $\displaystyle N(\epsilon)=1+\left\lfloor \frac{e^b\,\max^2(a,b)}{\epsilon}-a \right\rfloor$ and we are done!

Comment: That's a clean approach +1

Comment: Your solution is fantastic, thank you so much. However, I don't completely follow you from the second to the third line (in which you pull out the $e^x$ form the absolute value. Should there be an equals sign there? I may have may be missing something but I can't seem to put that together.

Comment: You're welcome!  And thank you!  Recall that $e^x-e^y=e^x(1-e^{y-x})$.  Now let $y=x/(1+x/n)$.

Comment: Of course, my mistake. Simple algebra and exhaustion don't mix well. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Is there a typo in your inequality (2)?  It seems like you used $\log(1+x) \geq \frac{x}{x+1}$ for $x > -1$.

Comment: @strants Thanks.  I've edited.

Answer (score 7):

To find your sequence $(a_n)$ where $|(1 + x/n)^n - e^x| \leqslant a_n \to 0$ -- proving uniform convergence on any bounded interval -- use the inequality $\ln(1+y) \leqslant y$.

We have for $0 \leqslant y < 1$,

$$1+y \leqslant e^y = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^k}{k!} \leqslant  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} y^k = \frac1{1-y},$$

Take $y = x/n$. It follows that for $n$ sufficiently large

$$1 + \frac{x}{n} \leqslant e^{x/n} \leqslant \left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^{-1},$$

and

$$\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n \leqslant e^x \leqslant \left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}.$$

The second inequality implies that

$$e^{-x} \geqslant \left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}.$$

Using Bernoulli's inequality $(1 - x^2/n^2)^n \geqslant 1 - x^2/n.$

Hence,

$$0 \leqslant e^{x} - \left(1+ \frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^{x}\left[1 - e^{-x}\left(1+ \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}\right]\\ \leqslant e^{x}\left[1 - \left(1+ \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}\left(1- \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}\right]\\= e^{x}\left[1 - \left(1- \frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^{n}\right]\leqslant e^{x}\frac{x^2}{n}.$$

Therefore, for all $x \in [0,K]$, we have as $n \to \infty$

$$0 \leqslant \left|e^{x} - \left(1+ \frac{x}{n}\right)^n\right| \leqslant e^K\frac{K^2}{n} \rightarrow 0.$$

An almost identical argument for $y \geqslant 0$ shows that

$$0 \leqslant e^{-y} - \left(1- \frac{y}{n}\right)^n \leqslant  e^{-y}\frac{y^2}{n}.$$

Thus if $-y = x \in [-L,0]$ we have

$$0 \leqslant \left|e^{x} - \left(1+ \frac{x}{n}\right)^n\right| = \left|e^{-y} - \left(1- \frac{y}{n}\right)^n\right| \leqslant \frac{L^2}{n} \rightarrow 0.$$

proving uniform convergence on any bounded interval.

Comment: Your last assertion is incorrect: $f_n(x) = \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ is unbounded on any semi-infinite interval $(-\infty,K]$, so it cannot converge uniformly.  (Specifically, your argument requires taking $n$ large relative to $|x|$ in line 2, which cannot be done on unbounded intervals). Otherwise, though, this is a solid argument, +1

Comment: @Strants:  Thanks. You're correct. I'll take that out.

Answer (score 5):

If you're not familiar with Dini's theorem (I wasn't), work from the power series of $\exp$.  Observe that
$$(1+x/n)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \frac{x^k}{n^k}$$
and that
$${n \choose k} \frac{1}{n^k} = \frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!k!} \to \frac{1}{k!}$$

This means that each coefficient in the expansion of $g_n(x) = \exp(x) - \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.  Also, all of the coefficients are positive and less than $\frac{1}{k!}$.

Now, consider the interval $[-R,R]$.  Choose $k> 0$ such that $\sum_{s=k+1}^\infty \frac{R^s}{s!} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ (why can you do this?)  For $n$ sufficiently large, we can make each of the first $k+1$ coefficients smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{2(k+1)(1+R^k)}$, so for any $x \in [-R,R]$,
$$|g_n(x)| \le  \sum_{s=0}^k \frac{\epsilon R^s}{2(k+1)(1+R^k)} + \sum_{s=k+1}^\infty \frac{R^s}{s!} \le \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

This same reasoning extends (with minor changes) to any bounded interval $[a,b]$ of $\mathbb{R}$ (and even half-open or open intervals).

Comment: This works.  I found another approach that is straightforward, doesn't require splitting into cases, and leads directly to a number "$N(\epsilon)$."

Answer (score 0):

Use the following limit: $\forall x\in\mathbb R$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }{n}\left[\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n-e^x\right]
=\frac{-x^2e^x}{2}.$$
Fro detail you can refer [Limit](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h524472p2965488).

For any given $a>0$, when $x\in[-a,a]$,
by above limit, we get
$$0\leq\lim_{n\to\infty }{n}\left|\left[\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n-e^x\right]\right|=\frac{x^2e^x}{2}\leq\frac{a^2e^a}{2}=:M.$$
So there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that when $n>N$,
$$\left|\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n-e^x\right|\leq\frac{M}{n},\quad \forall x\in[-a,a].$$