# Evaluating Nested Limits

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, exponential-function

In my attempt to prove $\frac d{dx}\left(e^x\right)=e^x$, I arrived at the following step:
$$\frac d{dx}\left(e^x\right)=e^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}$$
At this point, I substituted in 
$$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n}$$
to arrive at
$$\frac d{dx}\left(e^x\right)=e^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^{nh}}-1}{h}$$
Then, I let $h=\frac 1n$ to get
$$\frac d{dx}\left(e^x\right)=e^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1+h)^{h\left(\frac 1h\right)}-1}{h}$$
at which point a lot of things simplify and the limit is clearly equal to one. My question concerns the $h=\frac 1n$ step. While I see why this might be true, I don't really have a good conceptual or mathematical grasp of why this works, or whether this is even valid at all. Can the nested limit just be removed that way and $n$ replaced, or is there something else at work here?

Comment: If you can prove the double limit exists (perhaps without evaluating it), then this holds.

Comment: Can you give me a counterexample where the double limit not existing might lead to an incorrect result?

Comment: Easy.  Consider the following limit: $$\lim_{h\to0}\lim_{x\to\infty}xh$$

Comment: Ah, interesting. Can it be said at all whether this limit evaluates? As in, is there a single solution to it?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt The OP was not interchanging the limits, but rather illegitimately setting one independent parameter as a function of the other independent one.  We can appeal here to the Moore-Osgood Theorem to show that we can interchange the order of limits.   I've posted a solution with three ways forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not legitimate to let $h=1/n$ since $h$ and $n$ are ***independent parameters***.  We can still proceed along any of the following ways forward.

---

**METHODOLOGY $1$:**

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2036694/show-that-1-fracxnn-rightarrow-ex-uniformly-on-any-bounded-interval/2037515#2037515), I showed that $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ converges uniformly to $e^x$ on any bounded interval of the real line.

Therefore, the function $\frac{d}{dx}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n=\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{n-1}$ converges uniformly to $e^x$ on any bounded interval of the real line.

Hence, $\frac{de^x}{dx}=e^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:**

In [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the exponential function satisfies the inequalities

$$1+x\le e^x\le \frac{1}{1-x}$$

for $x<1$.  Therefore, we can write for $0<h<1$

$$1\le \frac{e^h-1}h\le \frac{1}{1-h}$$

whence application of the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{e^h-1}h=1$$

A parallel development for $h<0$ results in the same conclusion.  And we are done.

---

**METHODOLOGY $3$:**

In [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183291/exchange-of-two-limits-of-a-function/2183554#2183554), I discuss the [Moore-Osgood Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Sufficient_condition), which permits the interchange of limits if one of the two limits converges pointwise and the other uniformly.

It can be shown that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{nh}-1}{h}=n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)$ and the convergence is uniform for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Hence, the Moore-Osgood Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{nh}-1}{h}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{nh}-1}{h}\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty} n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

as expected again!

Comment: Very thorough +1 and I see another mention of Moore Osgood theorem.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you Paramanand!  And that Theorem is actually quite powerful.